# Sum values of columns for multiple groups in Oracle table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with a list of people, gender, race, & their group. It has 2000 records divided into 8 groups. I am trying to use PL/SQL to get the sum of people per gender per race for each group. I was thinking I should have a cursor populate a variable called v_group with the 8 groups, and then loop through all the records and get the counts for each one. It will put each count into their own variable and then insert the new summed up counts and the corresponding group into a table.

Here is a sample of what I have so far.

```
OPEN cur_get_group;     
LOOP
    v_group := '';
    FETCH cur_get_group
       INTO v_group;
    EXIT WHEN cur_get_group%NOTFOUND;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_hisp_m FROM mytable WHERE sex = 'M' AND ethn_code = 'H';
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_hisp_f FROM mytable WHERE sex = 'F' AND ethn_code = 'H';
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_cauc_m FROM mytable WHERE sex = 'M' AND ethn_code = 'C';
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_cauc_f FROM mytable WHERE sex = 'F' AND ethn_code = 'C';

    INSERT INTO mynewtable
    (group, hisp_m, hisp_f, cauc_m, cauc_f)
    VALUES
    (v_group, v_hisp_m, v_hisp_f, v_cauc_m, v_cauc_f);
    COMMIT;            

END LOOP;
```

Am I on the right track here? Do I need to do the loop differently?

Comment: So you are entering the **same** count values into each group's record, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relational data bases work on the set of data matching conditions and are very good at it. They are however very poor single item processing. Learn to think is terms of sets. Your process has to pass the source data table 5 times (1 for group and count process) While loops are sometimes a necessary evil they are a process of last resort. This can be done in 1 statement, passing the source 1 time.

```
insert into mynewtable
     (group, hisp_m, hisp_f, cauc_m, cauc_f)

select group_code
     ,  sum(hisp_m)
     ,  sum(hisp_f)
     ,  sum(cauc_m)     
     ,  sum(cauc_f)  
  from    
       ( select group_code,
              , case when sex = 'F' AND ethn_code = 'H' then 1 else 0 end hisp_f
              , case when sex = 'M' AND ethn_code = 'H' then 1 else 0 end hisp_m
              , case when sex = 'F' AND ethn_code = 'C' then 1 else 0 end cauc_f              
              , case when sex = 'M' AND ethn_code = 'C' then 1 else 0 end cauc_m
           from youroldtable
        )
group by group_code;
```

BTW DO NOT use group as a column name. It is a reserved word and doing so will lead to very difficult to find errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you want to use `pivot`:

```
with rws as (
  select 'F' sex, 'H' eth from dual connect by level <= 3
  union all
  select 'F' sex, 'C' eth from dual connect by level <= 4
  union all
  select 'M' sex, 'H' eth from dual connect by level <= 2
  union all
  select 'M' sex, 'C' eth from dual
) 
  select * from rws
  pivot (
    count (*) for ( sex, eth ) in (
      ( 'F', 'H' ) fh,
      ( 'F', 'C' ) fc,
      ( 'M', 'H' ) mh,
      ( 'M', 'C' ) mc
    )
  );

FH    FC    MH    MC   
    3     4     2     1
```

And insert the result of this query to the table.

Comment: Where am I getting values from mytable in this?

Comment: Replace `rws` with your table